# Why does my AWS Lambda Function restart with no error?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a simple Python AWS lambda function which is called every 15 minutes using eventbridge.

It runs perfectly for months on end than randomly with no error at all, will restart itself midway.

The log shows no warning but I do need a "No Refresh Required" which is the first line of code.  The issue I have is that it's calling an API and sometimes generates duplicates:

```
 2023-08-03T13:36:57.743+01:00 INIT_START Runtime Version: python:3.9.v26 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2::runtime:
 2023-08-03T13:36:59.297+01:00  No Refresh Required 
...
...
...
2023-08-03T13:37:21.236+01:00   No Refresh Required
```

I've got the timeout set at 2 minutes which is well within the 24 seconds above but I did notice that the external API usually responds within a second or two, but when it restarts it does appear to be taking longer ~ 10 seconds.

I appreciate there is no code here but given there are no errors, no warnings and it works for months without failure I feel this is AWS Lambda related, there is no timeout error and I have a try except, I am curious as to thoughts of ways to isolate what may be causing this.